# How to solve "Waiting until last debugger command completes" stuck in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

My project is in *Android Studio*. It has around 35 thousand lines in a *Windows 7*. My environment is updated.  I use *Kotlin* and not *Java*, but it's not important. I have lot of memory in my computer.

I read all material in Internet about the message `Waiting until last debugger command completes` while debuggng my app in the cell phone.

For me, the debugger works in normal pace, or it stucks (hangs) completely, or sometimes it's very slow.

I have threads in my app, but many times this problem occurs outside of any thread. Just in plain code!

I've posted it as a bug in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166132170) and [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249477), including the `dump file` and `idea.log` file. Google has stamped the priority as `P3` and severity as `S3` (low levels). *JetBrains* have answered me and I've produced many dumps and screenshots. They have  claimed that the problem can only be *Google*'s. Too much time has passed with no more positioning by *JetBrains* but today (Out/2) *Andrei Kuznetsov* from JetBrains has given me one suggestion (item **f** below)

Possible workarounds that can't solve my problem:

**a)** Erase all watch variables. Improves a little bit.

**b)** Erase old breakpoints. It's not enough.

**c)** Execute `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

**d)** Uncheck `Enable ToString object view` in `Settings`, `Build,Execution and Deployment`, `Debugger`, `Data Views`, `Java`

**e**) `Disable JIT` is unchecked in `Debugger` settings

**f**) I try to disable the option `Force classic VM for JDK 1.3x and earlier` in `Debugger` settings, but it also doesn't work.

**g**) In [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37045263) issue tracker in *Google* from 2015,  I've read a tip about trying to change in some *breakpoint* the  `Suspend` type from `all` to `Thread` and make this option  default.

**h**) During running, in debug window, click in some variable with right mouse button, and select `Mute Rendering`, that generates a big overhead in debuggin session. It was saved for future sessions. (*JetBrains* suggestion)

**i**) Now I'm trying go to `Settings -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java` and disable the option `Enable alternative view for Collections classes` (From [fireb86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373333/fireb86) answer). Let's see what happens.

-/-

There are *JetBrains* reports about this problem since [2008](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-42472)!

**Disclaimer**: It contains many updates I since I've asked the original question. I join all information to make reading this issue more fluid.

Comment: Any solution? I'm stuck with the same problem for the last few hours and I can't debug my app.

Comment: They (Jet Brains and Google) are ignoring the issue tracker that I've posted.

Comment: I downgraded my android studio from 4.2 to 4.1 and everything was working again.

Comment: I am impressed by their disregard for users.

Answer (score 6):

I've this issue for a few months with Idea 2020.2 + android plugin and, **in my case**, I resolved by disabling:

Settings -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java -> Enable alternative view for Collections classes (enabled by default)

and

Settings -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java -> Enable ToString object view (enabled by default)

as recommended by [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37045263#comment84)

Comment: **1)** default  `as a Thread`:  (I already did it). 
**2)** Disable `Enable alternative view for Collections classes`  (I will try it and I will report here)
**3)** Disable `Enable ToString object view`: (I already do it)

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum I edited my solution because the debugger works well with breakpoints with both "Suspend: Thread" and "Suspend: All" so I suppose the guilty is "Enable alternative view for Collections classes"

Comment: I will try this for some time and I will report here the results.

Comment: I'd made an update in my question based on your suggestion. I need some time to check if it solves the problem.

Comment: Since the problem persists in Arctic Fox and (AFAIK) the menu flow is now nothing like it was in Nov 2020, I'll point out that `Enable alternative view for Collections classes` can be found by right-clicking in the `Variables tab` and selecting `Customize Data Views`. By de-selecting `Enable alternative view for Collections classes` and `Enable ToString object view`, the problem went away (for ME). (FWIW: Before these changes, debugging froze while attempting to evaluate a `Boolean` expression that queries an SQLite database.)

Comment: Great @DSlomer64! I will try it and I will report my results in this question.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work for me, running a Java project with Gradle on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2. Win 10 Pro. Jetbrains need to get their $ together...
Not sure why Google is forcing developers to use a half broken IDE.